# A 3m wide path runs around a rectangular court. The length is 1.5 times the width. The area of the path is 1596 square metres. What are the dimensions

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, area

A path, 3 metres wide, runs around the outside edge of a rectangular court. The court is half as long again as it is wide. The area of the path is 1596 square metres. What are the dimensions of the court?
I got the dimensions to be 173.33 recurring metres by 86.66 recurring metres. Is this correct?

Comment: The title says length is 2 times width, but the body says length is 1.5 times width. There are two responses and each answers one of those options. Please fix the ambiguity (preferably by editing the title).

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the picture here the process is straightforward; let $x$ be the length of the court, so that $2x$ is the width. Then the path consists of two $3\times x$ rectangles along the length, two $3\times 2x$ rectangles along the width, and four $3\times 3$ squares for each corner. Thus the area of the path is 
$$
6x+12x+16;
$$ 
so we have $18x+36=1596$, giving $x=86.\overline{6}$ as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly get the perimeter of the court by subtracting all the $3\times 3= 9 m^2$ corners  from the area, $1596-36 = 1560 m^2$, then dividing by the width $1560/3=520m$ perimeter.

Then - here is your misunderstanding - the length is "half as much again", $1.5\times $ the width $w$, giving the perimeter $520=5w$ so $w=104m$ and the length $l = \frac 32w = 156m$.